# Visual Studio: how to add nuget packages as references when doing "Restore NuGet packages"

Tags: c#, visual-studio

I have downloaded all the packages using "Restore NuGet packages" that existed in `packages.config`

However, they do not appear in the References, so VS is not aware of them.

Is there a way to add them automatically to the reference list? Possibly in 1 step?

[image]

Comment: Have you tried building the solution? It should be automatic.

Comment: Yes, getting compile time errors because of missing assembly references.

Comment: What version of VS do you have?

Comment: 2017 Enterprise (15.2)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The references are tracked as part of the project files and are usually added as part of a NuGet package's initial installation. Restoring the packages will just download them.

This means it sounds like you need to reinstall those specific packages whose references are missing.

To do this, [run the `Update-Package` command in the Package Manager Console with the `-reinstall` flag on it](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/nuget/consume-packages/reinstalling-and-updating-packages).

```
Update-Package <package_name> -ProjectName MyProject -reinstall
```

Optionally, you can [add the `-Version` flag](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/nuget/tools/ps-ref-update-package) if you need to stick with a version that's not the latest, just make this version number match that stored in your packages.config file.

Or alternatively, to reinstall all packages for a given project:

```
Update-Package -Reinstall -ProjectName <project_name>
```

Comment: Thanks, this helped.

Comment: Apparently, you really need to use the Package Manager Console. Uninstalling and reinstalling via the Package Manager Gui did not work.

Answer (score 0):

I too have VS 2017. However, I haven't encountered any problem with Nuget packages.

Anyway, try this: Right-click the References folder in the project, then click "Manage Nuget Packages" then click "Restore".

If that doesn't work, close VS, delete all files in bin, obj and packages folders and then repeat the steps above.

Also make sure the items "Allow NuGet to download missing packages" and "Automatically check for missing packages during build..." are checkekd in Tools/Options/Nuget Package Manager setting as follows:
[image]